# Cross Referencing Data Written to a text file with a existing Database in Delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7

Im trying to cross reference data written to a text file With a Existing Database IE (check if the data written to the text file already exists in the database).

I have already created the program that writes the users login data (Name and Password) to a text file then i have started to write a algorithm to read data from the text file,but i am a bit stuck i have the Name Stored in the first line of the text file and the password (String values only) stored in the next line.

I have no idea how you would check if this data is already existing in the database,would you need to first extract the contents of the database first? or could you just cross reference it directly with the Database? I Have already created the Database(UserData.accdb) but i have not yet linked it up to the Form. This is what i have so far:

```
procedure TForm1.btnclickClick(Sender: TObject);

var
 tRegister      :    TextFile;
 Sline          :    String;
 Sname,SPword   :    String;

begin
  Assignfile(tRegister,'register.txt');

Try
 Reset(tRegister);

 except
   Showmessage('File Register.txt does not exist');
   Exit;
 end;

 While not EOF(tRegister) do
   ReadLn(tRegister,Sline);
     Sname:=Copy(Sline);

      // This is where i want to add code 

      end;



   end;

end.
```

Please don't be to harsh i am still new to Delphi :)

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you mean by "cross reference" (example textfile/database data). And please use some dots to seperate the sentences.

Comment: What does "cross reference" mean? What database? (There's no indication of one anywhere in your code.) Can you [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking? Some punctuation, proper capitalization, and paragraph breaks would make it easier to read, while you're at it. Thanks.

Comment: OP: `its just the Name in the first line` , really ? Why you're looking for `,` then. `iPosComma:=Pos(',',Sline);` !!

Comment: Your edit adds very little info. `// This is where I want to add code`? Great. You should add code at that point. You have still not explained where a "database" enters into things, or what you mean by "cross-reference". (Actually, you've added a new bit of confusion - what does "I've not yet linked it up" mean?

Comment: @KenWhite i'm still new to this so please don't be to harsh i would just like to connect a Access database table to the application and have a piece of code read the contents of the Text file and check if the values already exist in the Database if they do it will return a error message saying the user already exists otherwise it will write the new Data from the text file to the database that's the logic behind it i'm just not sure how to implement it hope this makes better sense know

Answer (score 1):

I understand from your question that you're currently stuck trying to check if a particular record exists in your database. I'll answer that very briefly because there are plenty similar questions on this site that should help you flesh out the detail.

However the title of your question asks about "Cross Referencing Data Written to a text file with a existing Database". From the description it sounds as if you're trying to reconcile data from two sources and figure what matches and what doesn't. I'll spend a bit more time answering this because I think there'll be more valuable information.

---

#### To check for data in a database, you need:

- A connection component which you configure to point to your database.
- A query component linked to the connection component.
- The query text will use a SQL statement to select rows from a particular table in your database.
- I suggest your query be parametrised to select specifically the row you're looking for (I'll explain why later.)
- **NOTE**: You could use a table component instead of a query component and this will change how you check for existing rows. It has the advantage you won't need to write SQL code. But well written SQL will be more scalable.

The options above vary by what database and what components you're using. But as I said, there are many similar questions already. With a bit of research you should be able to figure it out.

If you get stuck, you can ask a more specific question with details about what you've tried and what's not working. (*Remember this is not a free "do your work for you service", and you will get backlash if it looks like that's what you're expecting*.)

---

#### Reconciling data between text file and database:

There are a few different approaches. The one you have chosen is quite acceptable. Basically it boils down to:

1. for each `Entry` in `TheFile`
2. .. if the `Entry` exists in `TheDatabase`
3. .. .. do something with `Entry`
4. .. .. otherwise do something else with `Entry`

The above steps are easy to understand, so it's easy to be confident the algorithm is correct. It doesn't matter if there aren't one-liners in Delphi to implement those steps. As a programmer, you have the power to create any additional functions/procedures you need.
It is just important that the structure of the routine be kept simple.

Any of the above steps that cannot be very trivially implemented, you then want to break down into smaller steps: 2.a. 2.b. ; 3.a. 3.b. 3.c. ; etc. (This is what is meant by top-down design.)

> **TIP**: You want to convert all the different breakdowns into their own functions and procedures. This will make maintaining your program and reusing routines you've already written much easier.

I'm going to focus on breaking down step 2. How you do this can be quite important if your database and text files grow quite large. For example you could implement so that: every time you call the function to check "if `Entry` exists", it looks at every single record in your database. This would be very bad because if you have `m` entries in your file and `n` entries in your database you would be doing `m x n` checks.

*Remember I said I'd explain why I suggest a parametrised query*?

Databases are designed and written to manage data. Storing and retrieving data is their primary function, so let it do the work of finding out if the entry you're looking for exists. If for example you wrote your query to fetch all entries into your Delphi app and search there:

- Increase the memory requirements of your application.
- But more importantly, without extra work, expose yourself to the `m x n` problem mentioned above.

With a parametrised query, each time `if EntryExists(...)` is called you can change the parameter values and effectively ask the database to look for the record. The database does the work, and gives you an answer. So you might for example write your function as follows:

```
function TForm1.EntryExists(const AName: string): Boolean;
begin
  qryFindEntry.Close;
  qryFindEntry.Parameters.ParamByName('EntryName').Value := AName;
  qryFindEntry.Open;

  Result := qryFindEntry.RecordCount > 0;
end;
```

> **TIP**: It will be very important that you define an index on the appropriate columns in your database, otherwise every time you open the query, it will also search every record.

**NOTE**: Another option that is very similar would be to write a stored procedure on your database, and use a stored procedure component to call the database.

---

#### Additional comments:

**Your routine to process the file is hard-coded to use `register.txt`**

This makes it not-reusable in its current form. Rather move the code into a separate method: `procedure ProcessFile(AFileName: string);`. Then in your button click event handler call: `ProcessFile('register.txt');`.

> **TIP**: In fact it is usually a good idea to move the bulk your code out of event handlers into methods with appropriate parameters. Change your event handler to call these methods. Doing this will make your code easier to maintain, test and reuse.

**Your exception handling is wrong**

This is an extremely bad way to do exception handling.

**First**, you don't want to ever write unnecessary exception handling. It just bloats your code making it more difficult to read and maintain. When an exception is raised:

- The program starts exiting code to the innermost **finally**/**except** block. (So an exception would already exit your routine - as you have added code to do.)
- By default, an unhandled exception (meaning one you haven't swallowed somewhere) will be handled by the application exception handler. By default this will simply show an error dialog. (As you have added code to do.)
- The only change your code makes is to show a different message to the one actually raised. The problem is that you've made an incorrect assumption. "File not exists" is not the only possible reason `Reset(tRegister);` might raise an exception:

  - The file may exist, but be exclusively locked.
  - The file may exist, but you don't have permission to access it.
  - There may be a resource error meaning the file is there but *can't* be opened.
- So the only thing all your exception handling code has done is introduce a bug because it now has the ability to hide the **real reason** for the exception. Which can make troubleshooting much more difficult.

If you want to provide more information about the exception, the following is a better approach:

```
try
  Reset(tRegister);
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    //Note that the message doesn't make any assumptions about the cause of the error.
    E.Message := 'Unable to open file "'+AFileName+'": ' + E.Message;
    //Reraise the same exception but with extra potentially useful information.
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

The **second** problem is that even though you told the user about the error, you've hidden this fact from the rest of the program. Let's suppose you've found more uses for your `ProcessFile` method. You now have a routine that:

- Receives files via email messages.
- Calls ProcessFile.
- Then deletes the file and the email message.

If an exception is raised in `ProcessFile` and you swallow (handle) it, then the above routine would delete a file that was not processed. This would obviously be bad. If you hadn't swallowed the exception, the above routine would skip the delete step because the program is looking for the next **finally**/**except** block. At least this way you still have record of the file for troubleshooting and reprocessing once the problem is resolved.

The **third** problem is that your exception handler is making the assumption your routine will always have a user to interact with. This limits reusability because if you now call `ProcessFile` in a server-side application, a dialog will pop up with no one to close it.

Leaving unresolved exceptions to be handled by the application exception handler means that you only need to change the default application exception handler in the server application, and all exceptions can be logged to file - without popping up a dialog.